# Can't create database in SQL Server Express 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

One of our clients is running Windows Small Business Server 2011, and they have a SQL 2005 Server Express instance (and several other versions also installed).

Using Management Studio, running as administrator, I cannot seem to create any databases. The error I get is:

> Could not obtain exclusive lock on database 'model'. Retry the operation later.
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1807)

The first time this happened, there happened to be a backup task running which had a lock, so I tried again later, and still had the issue. Running EXEC sp_who2 shows only my own user with 2 locks on the model db, both are "sleeping", and seem to come from the Management Studio (.Net SQL Client, same last batch as when I started the app).

Unfortunately I mostly work with MySQL, so all this MS stuff is over my head.

**Edit:**

Here is the result of `SELECT  * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE DB_NAME(dbid) = 'model'`

Result:

```
+------+------------------------------+------+-----+-------------+------------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------+------------------+----------------------+
| spid |         lastwaittype         | dbid | uid | physical_io | login_time | open_tran |   status    | hostname | hostprocess |       cmd        |       loginame       |
+------+------------------------------+------+-----+-------------+------------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------+------------------+----------------------+
|    1 | SLEEP_TASK                   |    0 |   1 |           0 | 12:45.8    |         0 | background  |          |             | RESOURCE MONITOR | sa                   |
|    2 | LAZYWRITER_SLEEP             |    0 |   1 |           0 | 12:45.8    |         0 | background  |          |             | LAZY WRITER      | sa                   |
|    3 | LOGMGR_QUEUE                 |    0 |   1 |           0 | 12:45.8    |         0 | suspended   |          |             | LOG WRITER       | sa                   |
|    4 | REQUEST_FOR_DEADLOCK_SEARCH  |    0 |   1 |           0 | 12:45.8    |         0 | background  |          |             | LOCK MONITOR     | sa                   |
|   52 | MISCELLANEOUS                |    3 |   1 |           0 | 05:14.5    |         0 | sleeping    | BH-SBS   |        6976 | AWAITING COMMAND | BH\nuser             |
|   62 | MISCELLANEOUS                |    3 |   1 |           0 | 04:13.0    |         0 | sleeping    | BH-SBS   |        6976 | AWAITING COMMAND | BH\nuser             |
|   74 | MISCELLANEOUS                |    3 |   1 |           5 | 02:23.1    |         0 | runnable    | BH-SBS   |       22436 | SELECT           | BH\nuser             |
+------+------------------------------+------+-----+-------------+------------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------+------------------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really think the problem is creating the database with model as active database as [Reaces](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/37971/reaces) mentioned in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/119868/10832).

It is possible to create a new database using

```
USE Model
GO
CREATE DATABASE TEST;
GO
```

The issue might be some process or session holding lock on the model database and the `CREATE Database` statement not able to acquire the exclusive lock required.

Check what processes are currently using the model database, you can use

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.sysprocesses
WHERE   DB_NAME(dbid) = 'model'
```

Depending on what sessions are running, you can probably issue a `KILL <SPID>`, where `<SPID>` is the `session_id` of the session holding a lock on `model`, and try creating the database again.

**Update: Here is a query to find what sessions are currently running, the locks requested and additional information:** (Run on model database)

```
SELECT  resource_type ,
    request_session_id ,
    t.TEXT AS Command,
    request_mode ,
    request_type, request_status,
    s.program_name, s.status
FROM    sys.dm_tran_locks l JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions s 
ON l.request_session_id = s.session_id
    JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests r ON r.session_id = l.request_session_id
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) t
WHERE   resource_database_id = DB_ID()
```

Comment: [Max Vernon](http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/10832/max-vernon), Thanks for the edit.

Comment: See edit to question. I trimmed down the columns and posted the results of the 2nd query you have in your answer. The 1st query still gave the same error I had before.

Comment: Did you try restarting SSMS from which you are running the queries?

Comment: Yup. Many times. :/

Comment: @QuickDanger I updated my answer with a new query, run that on the model database and add all the results to the question.

Comment: Sometimes it will show a backup process, but even when I wait for this latest query to return no results and re-run the creation query, it will still hit the same error.

Comment: copy paste the code you are using to create the database here.

Comment: I have tried the graphical tool, your query, and reaces' query. They all generally look like: `USE Model
GO
CREATE DATABASE Evictions;
GO` (comment has line breaks where you have them, but the site removes line breaks in comments)

Comment: Are you creating the databases on a test server or local machine which you can reboot?

Comment: Boy I *wish* I could reboot it. I'm trying to install another instance of SQL Express to see if I can do it on a clean install.

Comment: Turns out a new install requires a reboot anyway... I'll test this for posterity after the reboot, but not sure when that will be. Thanks for your help thus far though!

Comment: Ok. If you could post an update after the reboot, it may help others who get the same error.

Comment: Deleted my answer, as yours covers more. However I was rather sure I had experienced a 2005 database creation that failed due to me being on the model db. It was however a 2000 in place upgrade to 2005, perhaps that mattered.